# using template declared in other file in c++

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have defined a template class in a file.

point.h is

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

using namespace std;

template <typename T, int size>
class point {
private:
    T coordinates[size];

public:
    point();
    void set_coordinates(const T *);
    void get_coordinates(T *);
};

#endif  /* POINT_H */
```

point.c is

```
#include "point.h"

template <typename T, int size>
point::point() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        coordinates[i] = 0;
}

template <typename T, int size>
void point<T, size>::set_coordinates(const T *coordinates) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        this->coordinates[i] = coordinates[i];
}

template <typename T, int size>
void point<T, size>::get_coordinates(T *coordinates) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        coordinates[i] = this->coordinates[i];
}
```

I am using this template as `point<int, 2> p0;`. But compiler gives error that `point<int, 2>` is not defined.
I searched on this and found two solutions -
1. to use `export` variable. But I read that it is not supported by all compilers. So, I don't want to use that.
2. to create explicit class specializations like

```
template <> class point<int> {
    ...
}
```

But isn't there any other way to do this? (I mean in C++ standard containers, they might have used some technique to do this.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574417/673730

Answer (score 2):

Read this and the next two FAQ questions - [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html)

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the c++ standard containers is keep everything in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

You should put all the definitions belonging to the template `point` (that is, including the member functions) to the `point.h` file and include it in any file that uses the `point` class, so that the compiler can instantiate it as needed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/51831) for details.

The C++ compilers and linkers have means to avoid "multiple definitions" error on link (the ODR rule in the standard states this must be the case).